# What causes the retina Macbook Pro HDMI-DVI output to cut out on occasion?

Tags: hdmi, macbook-pro, dvi

I got my retina Macbook Pro this week and have been waiting for my Thunderbolt to DVI adapters to get here so I can hook them up to my external displays. In the meantime, I am using an HDMI to DVI cable to hook up to my monitor.

I've noticed every once in a while, the monitor I am using will sometimes go blank for a second and then back. It doesn't happen very often, but I'm not sure if this has to do with the cable, monitor, or my retina Macbook Pro.

I've tried multiple cables, and have been using this monitor previously to the retina Macbook Pro, so I don't think the monitor is the issue.

Do you think this is an issue with the laptop? Something graphics card related? I can't seem to figure out why this randomly happens.

I was able to catch this happening on video...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vGeDR48E8w

Comment: What model of display/monitor are you using?  It sounds like it could be blanking out temporarily during an HDCP handshake.

Comment: I get the same issue with two different cables and two different displays (1080p monitor and 1080p TV) using a straight HDMI to HDMI connection each time. It happens only once within 10 minutes of first connecting up the display.

Comment: Any luck with this? Mine does the same thing.

Comment: Just as a datapoint, I have this same issue using a Mini-DP to Dual Link DVI adapter, as referenced in my answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57734/considerations-when-connecting-an-11-2011-mba-and-13-2012-mbp-to-a-2560x1440-d/57796#57796. I have yet to find the cause too..

Comment: Just tested, and the issue is still present on OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: I have the same issue with my RMBP. Annoying.

Comment: When it happens, does the backlight of the monitor turn off? For example: If you open a black image on full screen you will notice that even tough it's black, you can certainly tell it's on, (because the contrast is not perfect)

Comment: If the backlight DOES turn off, I will really suspect the problem is the monitor (and you have bad luck). The bad capacitors in the backlight power-supply, is by all means the most common failure mode in LCD monitors. When this model (i have the same) starts to fail, random blanks occur while the backlight power supply restarts.

Comment: @istepaniuk that's not it, see my note Jul 15 '12, it happens on both my displays.

Comment: This also happens to me,regardless if I am running Windows or OSX on my rMBP 15 inch. I'm running with the lid closed, and the laptop is not moved, nor are the cables disturbed. I'm using a DVI-D via Thunderbolt (which doesn't have this issue) and the HDMI port/cable with two identical Asus monitors. The HDMI cable is plugged directly into one of the monitors with no adapter. (FYIW-I'm using the other Thunderbolt for my Ethernet connection) I agree it is an annoyance.

Comment: This can happen with some poorly-screened cables if you put a mobile phone near or on the cable (with a DisplayPort cable, iPhone and Macbook Air mid-2011 model).  On same Macbook, this has also started happening if I move the Macbook horizontally bit - probably a bad connection within the Mini DisplayPort connector in Macbook, as it's fixable by pushing the cable a bit either way to re-make connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Automatic Graphics Switching in the System Preferences-Energy Saver.  This may be working for me, though I haven't figured out how to reproduce the 1-2 second blanking, so only time will tell.

I'm running 10.8.2 on a new rMBP and have the same issue - The external display goes blank for 1-2 seconds when connected to a 1680 x 1050 display via the HDMI connector and the rMBP is closed and in a stand. There is no movement of the rMBP, the HDMI cable or monitor when this happens.

I have not experienced the same momentary blanking of the rMBP's display when using only the native display.

It doesn't happen often (2-3 times per day) so it's more of an irritation that I don't expect from a nearly $3,000 piece of hardware.

Comment: I get the same thing... any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the connection from MBP to monitor:

MBP - Adapter - Cable - Monitor

Let's assume MBP has no problem, and you've ruled out your cable since you've tested many , also the monitor should is fine as it's working fine. That leaves the adapter.

And I've had experiences with a few bad adapters, and that has happened to me.

I am not completely sure if it's the problem, but I will start there. Since Retina MBP and MBP use the same graphics, so I don't think MBP is the problem.

Good Luck

Answer (score -2):

This is a known issue with OSX and the Retina MacBook Pro. Apple are currently working on a fix. OSX 10.8.1 is due shortly which should address the problem.

Comment: I've just updated to 10.8.1 and that does not fix the problem for me :(. Mine cuts out briefly when I move the computer even the slightest amount. I hope its a software issue as I dont really want to return the machine for such a small thing :(

Comment: Could you either update this with a bug report number (radar or http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1) or perhaps move this to comments?